# How to get dynamic HTML code from webpage without opening browser?

Tags: python, web-scraping

[This site](https://monitoringpublic.solaredge.com/solaredge-web/p/site/public?name=128223&locale=en_US#/dashboard) has an "export as csv" button next to the "Power and Energy" text. [This is the link](https://monitoringpublic.solaredge.com/solaredge-web/p/charts/274560/chartExport?st=1567296000000&et=1569887999999&fid=274560&timeUnit=4&pn0=Energy&id0=0&t0=0&hasMeters=false) of that button which can be found on browser's developer tools (Note that the link changes every 15 minutes)

My question is, is there any way to get that link using python without opening the browser? (I.e. without using selenium because it would take time if I did this for multiple sites.)

My goal is to automate the process of downloading that CSV file, every 1 hour.

Comment: If _without opening browser_ why _Selenium_?

Comment: Sorry, by mistake. Removed the tag.

Comment: Selenium with headless mode?

Comment: Well its basically selenium again so the overall time would be only slightly improved I guess.

Comment: Which tab of the chart? Day, month, year? I found js that could form the url but I need to know which chart you want.

Comment: @LuckyZakary I want the day tab.

Comment: @John It seems like a pretty trivial task I'm making a sample script for you, basically what they are doing is sending start time and end time in url param as st and et.

Comment: Yes I think the only solution would be to manually create that link every time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That url works in curl. Therefore the data doesn't depend on javascript and you do not need selenuim. The st and et are unix time:

```
datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(1567296000000/1000)
```

The timeUnit=4 is daily, so making that request hourly is wasting the site's resource and yours. If you really need hourly, change time timeUnit=3 and pn0=Power. Energy=Power x Hr

Lastly, I assume that since you are planning to run hourly, you are planning to save the data somewhere. If so, consider adjusting your st and et to only that range you need to further reduce your request size.

Comment: Yes I already followed this approach. Changing the timestamps for the day I want (which is the current day). Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

If you open your browsers debugging tools and go to the "Network" tab, you can see web requests as they are being made.

For example, the request for download from the site you linked is:

https://monitoringpublic.solaredge.com/solaredge-web/p/charts/274560/chartExport?st=1567296000000&et=1569887999999&fid=274560&timeUnit=4&pn0=Energy&id0=0&t0=0&hasMeters=false

The various URL parameters mean that that link will probably always point to that specific file (rather than one that is updated over time).

You can use this method to get the links for the other sites as well, but like this one, the URLs will probably point to a link for that specific time.

Comment: How can I find that request? I've went through all of the request names, and didn't find the csv file

Comment: Open the network tab in the debugging tools and then click on the download button on the webpage. [This](https://i.imgur.com/AA8Pxje.png) is what it looks like for me in Firefox. I then right clicked on it and clicked copy url

Comment: Thank you. But how could I get those requests using python without opening the browser?

Comment: I'm not sure you could. Unless you can find the Javascript that activates when you press the button, but I don't really have experience with things like that

Comment: I would accept your answer as well if I was allowed to. Thank you.